# ui-typeahead - Working with object levels

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a person object:

```
person = {};

person.city = {};

person.city.state = {};
```

**First** select the State

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="person.city.state" uib-typeahead="state as state.name for state in getState($viewValue)" >
```

**After** select the city based in **state selected**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="person.city" uib-typeahead="city as city.name for city in getCity($viewValue, person.city.state.id)" >
```

Everything okay when i select the state, but the city input get value '[object Object]' after selected the state, if i clean the city input value to type the search, the state input clean too.
any suggestion?

Comment: The directive does not have support to this situation, i need that only change the object value (ng-model) when selected some option listed.

Comment: I create variables auxiliaries to resolve this problem, the code grown, but was the only way that i found.